# How do I get the user@os to show up in front of commands in the shell

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, console, konsole

Currently my shell shows this:

[image]

It used to show up like `user@distro ~$`. How do I get that user@distro to show up in the terminal? I'm using Konsole as my terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it went away was because I overrode the PS1 variable in my .bashrc file. Setting it as follows got the desired effect I wanted:

```bash
PS1='\u@\h \w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\$ '
```

Specifically, '\u@\h' is the pattern I was alluding to in the title of my question.

**Edit**: removed the export per glenn jackman's comment.

Comment: That variable is just used by the shell, it doesn't need to be exported.

Comment: See also [6.9 Controlling the Prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) in the manual